# pre populated date which is not loading for the first time but loads everytime after that

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

1. The issue:

I need to pre-populate the systems date onto the disabled input box and this should only happen for a specific page. So i was using the href condition. Then i can see this working all the time but  if i test it as for the first time(IN MAC) i get this issue of date doesnt load. and it throws an error saying **cannot assign value to null** . Which means it is not finding the HTML code of **document.getelementbyid** at the start. But then if i refresh the page and check it loads fine(i checked it for 100 times). Then i saw that after a cache clear if i access that particular page i see that at the start it doesnt load but later on its working fine. And it has different JS files configured under one file, so is it causing an issue while loading?Am i missing something? Any solution for this?**(Only for MAC)**.

2. The JS code i have written is as follows:

   ```
    $(document).ready(function(){   
       if($(location).attr('href').indexOf("/ccpaRequest.html")) {    
         if($('div.ccpa-form-content').length){    
           var date = new Date();
           const months = ["JAN","FEB","MAR","APR","MAY","JUN","JUL","AUG","SEP","OCT","NOV","DEC"];
           const monthName = months[date.getMonth()];
           var d = date.getDate() + "-" + monthName + "-" + date.getFullYear();
           document.getElementById('DateField').value = d;   
         } 
       } 
    });
   ```
3. The HTML code written for the above:

   ```
   <div class="ccpa-form-content margin-top-20 marginLeft-10">
      <label class="ccpa-label" for="date">Date:
               <input type="text" id="DateField" name="DateField" disabled>
      </label>
   ```

Comment: What's the purpose of `  if($('div.ccpa-form-content').length) `?

Comment: @PhaniRithvij That is for ensuring that... That particular div has been loaded or not. So now the entire inside if code runs only when the div loads and the condition becomes true. So that i won't face an issue of the HTML tag not being loaded and  I'm assigning a value to a not loaded element. I hope i answered your question.

Comment: Hi Surya, I tried this code in a plunker and in mac, https://plnkr.co/edit/35xD8BhSomZmbFWP it seems to work fine for me. Is this happening in any specific browser? I tried in Chrome, Safari.